# ¿Como darle margen superior a un texto que tengo en una barra sin modificar el tamaño de la barra?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Hola tengo una barra superior que esta debajo del navbar a la cual le estoy tratando de poner un breadcrumb para que se pueda visualizar la dirección de donde se ubica el usuario pero también tengo un botón al final de la misma barra, el problema es que el breadcrumb se me encima para arriba y no se como centrarlo al mismo nivel que el botón, adjunto imágenes del código y del problema, gracias.

Codigo

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-end">
        <div class="col">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Pruebas</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-link text-muted text-decoration-none nav-toggle" href="#collapse1" onclick="controllerModal.onNew()">Agregar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Como se ve en la pagina, encimado para arriba el breadcrumb]

Comment: Listo, lo tomare en cuenta gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fácil (aunque desconozco si funcionará en todas partes) es agregarle el margen superior en la columna del breadcrumb directamente, usando la case **mt-2**

Ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mt-2">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Pruebas</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-link text-muted text-decoration-none nav-toggle" href="#collapse1" onclick="controllerModal.onNew()">Agregar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si me sirvió, Gracias